# Can not find edit request that I had skipped

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

I "skipped" a proposed edit in the review on https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/107909/42975 because I was editing myself quite a lot.
Now, I want to manually apply the useful fixes from it, but can not find the skipped edit diff.

Where to look?

*Update:*

Later, I found the edit again - but without noticing why, and how it ended up on my screen.

Now, while my current motivating instance of the problem was solved by chance - I could read the diff, and applly changes manually by a standard edit (of my own post) - the problem still exist.

It even seems like both parts of the confusion are related to a common cause, making it more relevant.

Could the problem be related to hiding parts of UI and feature set based on reputation?
(My rep. was about 650 at the time.)